# Lucene search with dashes does not return consistent results

Tags: indexing, lucene

Hi I have a problem with Lucene search does not return consistent results. 
Indexing is done with StandardAnalyzer and lucene version is 3.0

An example entry in database is

```
A1BC-1-12345678 - AU-01 / 123456 - No.1 ABC DEFG XX-YYY Example Data
```

If I search for the whole string, it will NOT return any results.

If I take out the single dashes and slashes, search for

```
A1BC-1-12345678 AU-01 123456 No.1 ABC DEFG XX-YYY Example Data
```

it will NOT return any results.

If I replace the dash between XX-YYY with whitespace, search for

```
A1BC-1-12345678 AU-01 123456 No.1 ABC DEFG XX YYY Example Data
```

--------it returns result!----------------------

Now if I include the dashes and slash, and replace the dash between XX-YYY with whitespace, search for

```
A1BC-1-12345678 - AU-01 / 123456 - No.1 ABC DEFG XX YYY Example Data
```

It will NOT return any results.

Finally if I replace the dash between both AU-01 and XX-YYY with whitespace, search for

```
A1BC-1-12345678 AU 01 123456 No.1 ABC DEFG XX YYY Example Data
```

it will NOT return any results.

In conclusion, "XX-YYY" is not valid but "AU-01" is valid, but "XX YYY" is valid and "AU 01" is not valid, so what seems to be the problem?

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: How are you searching?  Most likely this has to do with your analysis, but hard to say what the problem is without any details or code.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got an answer to this, according to Lucene doc, the StandardAnalyzer uses StandardTokenizer, and it is index based on:

- Splits words at punctuation characters, removing punctuation.
  However, a dot that's not followed by whitespace is considered part
  of a token.
- Splits words at hyphens, unless there's a number in the
  token, in which case the whole token is interpreted as a product
  number and is not split.

I think WhitespaceAnalyzer with Lowercase filter would suit my needs.